How to create links to our pages and sister sites from within comments and chat?
Apparently it is possible to use [crypto.se] to resolve to Cryptography, with a link to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ where the .se is short for Stack Exchange.
What other smart links can be created that are useful in comments on the Cryptography site, our Meta site and within chat?

Beware that this list is not exhaustive, please see the answer on magic links for more options. These are just the most useful ones for our site.
Within comments
For comments on posts we have:

[tour] links to the site's "Tour" page, useful for newbe's
[ask] links to the "How to Ask" page, works even in chat
[help/on-topic] links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic)
[help/dont-ask] links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask)
[edit] links to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit
[chat] links to the list of chat sites at https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=crypto.stackexchange.com, which includes our main chat room "the side channel"

So most of these won't work in chat, unless mentioned explicitly.
Of course the old [tag:tag-name] points to a specific tag, even in chat and posts, that hasn't changed.
Pointing to sites
These also work in chat!
For our own site, these generic links are useful:

[meta] links to Cryptography Meta, link https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com - only from our site of course
[main] links to Cryptography, link https://crypto.stackexchange.com, useful when chatting or commenting on Cryptography Meta

Then there are two shorthands for the most visited sites:

[so] creates Stack Overflow, link: https://stackoverflow.com, for programming related questions, including those that target cryptography
[su] creates Super User, link https://superuser.com, for tool related questions (exception for e.g. testing randomness, side channel attacks and very cryptography specific questions)
[sf] creates Server Fault, link https://serverfault.com, for server related questions (e.g. how to install certificates on a particular server)

More generic are sites that end with stackexchange.com, or .se in the smart links:

[crypto.se] creates Cryptography, link https://crypto.stackexchange.com - that's us 
[security.se] creates IT Security, link https://security.stackexchange.com, our friendly sister site
[math.se] creates Math, link https://math.stackexchange.com, for questions that are mostly about math rather than cryptography
[softwarerecs.se] creates Software Recommendations, link https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com


I've verified each and every one of these, but feel free to edit the wiki answer if you find you are using an additional link often, if any of the mentioned smart links don't work, or if it becomes more available, e.g. for Q/A posts or for chat.

Test: [crypto.se]
